# Squashing commits with some commits pulled from origin

Tags: git, github

I worked on a few local commits, pulled some commits from remote someone else did onto my local branch, then did a few more local commits. I want I did into one.

Problem is when when I do `git -log` this is listed:

> commit 1b6f7af1bdf21f397bab146fca11f74151b30e15 (HEAD -> bug_fixing,
>   origin/bug_fixing) Author: steve  Date:   Wed Jan
>   17 18:23:17 2018 -0500
>
> ```
> fix issued Play #30, #27, #26; GPL #240
> ```
>
> commit 069646ced4300bb30d6fbe33fbebb8e504e55de6 Merge: c215cbc3
>   23cf454b Author: steve  Date:   Wed Jan 17
>   18:17:12 2018 -0500
>
> ```
> downloadThread to Executor
> ```
>
> commit c215cbc3751092b00573152db2ced2369672497a Author: steve
>    Date:   Wed Jan 17 18:10:56 2018 -0500
>
> ```
> downloadThread to Executor
> ```
>
> commit 4dffc55b667580b3103b6c5f1d9f17ad1d95c134 Author: steve
>    Date:   Wed Jan 17 18:10:42 2018 -0500
>
> ```
> downloadThread to Executor
> ```
>
> commit 23cf454b4bf82fe9808259ac7cc76643d45869f8 (origin/play,
>   origin/HEAD) Author: geecko  Date:   Sun Jan 14
>   01:05:57 2018 +0100
>
> ```
> Show ID3 lyrics in floating window only if no connectivity
> ```

I would like to squash the first four commits there into one. However when I did `git rebase -i HEAD~4` I get the following in my editor:

```
pick 4dffc55b downloadThread to Executor
pick c215cbc3 downloadThread to Executor
pick 60c385c6 Change error message when requesting lyrics while missing both fingerprint and artist/title. Also refresh lyrics after being granted storage permission
pick ded8bea7 Add User Poll
pick 04e9484c Don't use appsee if user has had the app for more than a day
pick 37468ce2 Auto cancel the translation & survey notifications
pick ead6b151 Remove useless conditions
pick 7988b0b5 Add test device (AdMob)
pick 70da81e0 Fix NPE in OverlayContentLayout
pick 15f05ce1 Refresh MediaStore every once in a while
pick 923d63e9 Bump versionCode
pick 635543d9 Show resync button for API versions < Kitkat
pick 9b8de33a Retain user input inside UserPollActivity after rotation
pick 23cf454b Show ID3 lyrics in floating window only if no connectivity
pick 1b6f7af1 fix issued Play #30, #27, #26; GPL #240
```

which includes commits pulled from remote and and I'm not sure what to do. How do I squash just the first four commits listed in the log?

Answer (score 0):

Normally, if you want to squash just the first four commits listed in the log, you have to do:

`git reset --soft HEAD~4` and `git commit -m "new message"`

Comment: That seems to overwrite the history of the pulled commits

Comment: I maybe haven't understood. So now, your git log display ```A - download - download - download - B```. What git log do you expect after the '"fix" ? ```A - B ``` ? And another question: do you have unstaged changes ?